# Quickblox: arrays in custom objects are not being downloaded correctly

Tags: quickblox

```
- (void)loadUserInfoForId:(int)userId
{
    NSMutableDictionary *getRequest = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    [getRequest setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:userId] forKey:@"user_id"];
    [QBCustomObjects objectsWithClassName:@"orgeen_users_info" extendedRequest:getRequest delegate:self];
}

- (void)completedWithResult:(Result *)result
{
    if(result.success && [result isKindOfClass:QBCOCustomObjectPagedResult.class])
    {
        QBCOCustomObjectPagedResult *getObjectsResult = (QBCOCustomObjectPagedResult *)result;
        QBCOCustomObject *userInfo = getObjectsResult.objects[0];

        NSLog(@"array_test: %@", userInfo.fields[@"array_test"]);
    }
}
```

The output shows that fields[@"array_test"] = 558:

> array_test: 558

At the same time the admin panel shows that fields[@"array_test"] = {"123", "558"}:
[image]

And according to QB log output, that's true:

```
<array_test type="array">
      <array_test>123</array_test>
      <array_test>558</array_test>
    </array_test>
```

What am I doing wrong?

P.S. The problem is not that the wrong object is being downloaded, I checked by object and user id.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try QuickBlox iOS SDK 1.8.5
http://quickblox.com/developers/IOS#Framework_changelog:

It works ok